# How to Check Switch Bootstrap 5 with Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I want to do switch toggle with plain Javascript with a function. But it seems the loop inside this function doesn't work since it only can detect the default state. The if-else statement works when i try to manually set the state of the input. But, if i click the switch, nothing happens.
I use Bootstrap 5 Beta for this. Open to any better suggestion as long as it does not require framework/library/additional module other than the bootstrap bundle JS.

Here is my switch html code:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch mx-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pricingSwitch">
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript function:

```
function pricingTable() {
    console.log("Called")
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('pricingSwitch')

    var priceMonthly = document.getElementsByClassName("price-monthly")
    var priceAnnual = document.getElementsByClassName("price-annual")
    var durationMonth = document.getElementsByClassName("duration-month")
    var durationYear = document.getElementsByClassName("duration-year")

    console.log("Pre Loop")
    for (var i = 0; i < priceMonthly.length; i++) {
        console.log(checkbox.checked)
        console.log(i)
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            priceMonthly[i].style.display = "none"
            priceAnnual[i].style.display = "inline-block"
            durationMonth[i].style.display = "none"
            durationYear[i].style.display = "inline-block"
        } else if (checkbox.checked == false) {
            priceMonthly[i].style.display = "inline-block"
            priceAnnual[i].style.display = "none"
            durationMonth[i].style.display = "inline-block"
            durationYear[i].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it looks like i didnt add listener for the checkbox. This is the final working code

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('pricingSwitch')

var priceMonthly = document.getElementsByClassName("price-monthly")
var priceAnnual = document.getElementsByClassName("price-annual")
var durationMonth = document.getElementsByClassName("duration-month")
var durationYear = document.getElementsByClassName("duration-year")

function checker(checked) {
  checked ? showAnnual() : showMonthly()
}

function showAnnual() {
  priceMonthly[0].style.display = "none"
  priceAnnual[0].style.display = "inline-block"
  durationMonth[0].style.display = "none"
  durationYear[0].style.display = "inline-block"
}

function showMonthly() {
  priceMonthly[0].style.display = "inline-block"
  priceAnnual[0].style.display = "none"
  durationMonth[0].style.display = "inline-block"
  durationYear[0].style.display = "none"
}

checker(this.checked)

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
  checker(this.checked)
})
```